# symfony 4 - how to clear flash messages after 5second?

Tags: javascript, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony4, symfony-3.4

I am setting a flash message in my controller when rendering a twig template. i'm checking user email if exist in database flash will be green else red.
i want to clear the message flash after 5second but idk how.

twig.html

```
{#=======================(    )===========================#}
{#====================(          )========================#}
{#=================( flash messages )=====================#}
{#====================(          )========================#}
{#=======================(    )===========================#}

{% for message in app.flashes('notice') %}
    {% if var %}    
        <div class="flash-notice" style="background-color:red;">
            {{ message }}
        </div>
    {% else %}
        <div class="flash-notice" style="background-color:green;">
            {{ message }}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

controller.php

```
/**
 * @Route("/find_email", name="find_email")
 */
public function FindEmail(Request $request,EventDispatcherInterface $eventDispatcher)
{
    $user = new User();
    $email = $request->request->get("inputEmail", "valeur par défaut si le champ n'existe pas");

    $user = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository(User::class)
        ->findOneBy(['email' => $email]);
    ////////////////////////////////////
    if (!$user) {
        $var=true;
        $this->addFlash("notice", "This is an error message");  
    } else {
        $user_=$user;
        $var=false;
        $this->addFlash("notice", "This is a success message");
    }

    return $this->render('Security/reset_password.html.twig',[
        'form'=> $email,
        'var'=>$var,
    ]);
}
```

[image]

Comment: I think you want to hide/fade out the message after 5 seconds and not to clear? Because it's cleared after the next page reload.

Comment: thank you i fixed this problem

Answer (score 2):

You need to write a javascript function which removes `.flash-notice` five seconds after page load.